# Pytorch AssertionError: Size mismatch between tensors

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

This is the error I keep getting

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-cffc998d0a87> in <module>()
      1 train_ls = train(net, train_features, train_labels,
      2                  num_epochs, learning_rate,
----> 3                  weight_decay, batch_size)

1 frames
<ipython-input-37-e12556540edd> in train(net, train_features, train_labels, num_epochs, learning_rate, weight_decay, batch_size)
     26   train_ls = []
     27   train_tensor = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(train_features), 
---> 28                                                 torch.Tensor(train_labels))
     29   train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_tensor,
     30                                              batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in __init__(self, *tensors)
    165 
    166     def __init__(self, *tensors: Tensor) -> None:
--> 167         assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
    168         self.tensors = tensors
    169 

AssertionError: Size mismatch between tensors
```

and this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch import nn

train_link = "/content/pump-data/train_pumps.csv"
test_link = "/content/pump-data/test_pumps.csv"

train_data = pd.read_csv(train_link)
test_data = pd.read_csv(test_link)

train_data.status_group == "functional needs repair"

all_features = pd.concat((train_data.iloc[:, 1:-1], test_data.iloc[:, 1:]))

numeric_features = all_features.dtypes[all_features.dtypes != 'object'].index

all_features[numeric_features] = all_features[numeric_features].apply(
    lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / (x.std()))

all_features[numeric_features] = all_features[numeric_features].fillna(0)

all_features = pd.get_dummies(all_features, dummy_na=True)

n_train = train_data.shape[0]

train_features = torch.tensor(all_features[:n_train].values,
                              dtype=torch.float32)
test_features = torch.tensor(all_features[n_train:].values,
                             dtype=torch.float32)


train_labels = torch.tensor(train_data_new.values.reshape(-1, 1),
                            dtype=torch.float32)


class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
    super().__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features, 20)
    self.output = nn.Linear(20, out_features)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.output(x)
    return torch.sigmoid(x)


  loss = nn.BCELoss()
in_features = train_features.shape[1]

def train(net, train_features, train_labels,
          num_epochs, learning_rate, weight_decay, batch_size):
  train_ls = []
  train_tensor = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(train_features), 
                                                torch.Tensor(train_labels))
  train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_tensor,
                                             batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,
                               weight_decay=weight_decay)

  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_loss = 0
    for X, y in train_loader:
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      output = net(X)
      l = loss(output, y)
      l.backward()
      optimizer.step()
  
    epoch_loss += l.item() / len(train_loader)
    train_ls.append(lrmse)
    if(epoch%10==0):
      print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, lrmse))
  return train_ls


net = Net(in_features, 1)

num_epochs = 2
learning_rate = 0.80
weight_decay = 24
batch_size = 24

train_ls = train(net, train_features, train_labels,
                 num_epochs, learning_rate,
                 weight_decay, batch_size)
```

Comment: What is the size of `in_features` of your `train_features` ?

Comment: the size is 17311

Comment: Please show `train_features.shape` and `train_labels.shape`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this fix your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch import nn

# train_link = "/content/pump-data/train_pumps.csv"
# test_link = "/content/pump-data/test_pumps.csv"

# train_data = pd.read_csv(train_link)
# test_data = pd.read_csv(test_link)

# train_data.status_group == "functional needs repair"

# all_features = pd.concat((train_data.iloc[:, 1:-1], test_data.iloc[:, 1:]))

# numeric_features = all_features.dtypes[all_features.dtypes != 'object'].index

# all_features[numeric_features] = all_features[numeric_features].apply(
#     lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / (x.std()))

# all_features[numeric_features] = all_features[numeric_features].fillna(0)

# all_features = pd.get_dummies(all_features, dummy_na=True)

# n_train = train_data.shape[0]

# train_features = torch.tensor(all_features[:n_train].values,
#                               dtype=torch.float32)
# test_features = torch.tensor(all_features[n_train:].values,
#                              dtype=torch.float32)


# train_labels = torch.tensor(train_data_new.values.reshape(-1, 1),
#                             dtype=torch.float32)


class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
    super().__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features, 20)
    self.output = nn.Linear(20, out_features)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.output(x)
    return self.sigmoid(x)


loss = nn.BCELoss()

train_features = np.random.rand(128,17311)
train_labels = np.random.randint(0,2, (128,1))

in_features = train_features.shape[1]


def train(net, train_features, train_labels,
          num_epochs, learning_rate, weight_decay, batch_size):
  train_ls = []
  train_tensor = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(train_features), 
                                                torch.Tensor(train_labels))
  train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_tensor,
                                             batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,
                               weight_decay=weight_decay)

  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_loss = 0
    for X, y in train_loader:
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      output = net(X)
      l = loss(output, y)
      l.backward()
      optimizer.step()
  
    epoch_loss += l.item() / len(train_loader)
    train_ls.append(epoch_loss)
    if(epoch%10==0):
      print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, epoch_loss))
  return train_ls


net = Net(in_features, 1)

num_epochs = 30
learning_rate = 0.80
weight_decay = 24
batch_size = 24

train_ls = train(net, train_features, train_labels,
                 num_epochs, learning_rate,
                 weight_decay, batch_size)
```

Comment: sadly the result is the same but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have checked the code it runs fine with my tiny example. May your problem with the data. I edited my answer hope this can help you.